# Android custom ListView with TableRow within. setOnclickListener?

Tags: listview, tablerow, listitem, onitemclicklistener

I'd like an insight for this problem please.
I'm new to this ListView. I have managed to put in data from database, and set the id of list item to id of a DB record.

Everything OK when using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 for the layout and android.R.id.text1 for the TextView where my Text would be. 
I even set the setOnItemClickListener and got a Toast whit correct data (item position and the _id i have set).

Than I wanted to use a TableRow or TableLayout as a custom layout for list items. 
That works, but I don't know how to get reference to the Views in the TableRow (ie. TableRow itself)?

setOnItemClickListener stops working and I cannot use setOnclickListener on the row.

Is it possible to somehow use that kind of technique if I wanted to get POSITION and ID of a ListView item or should I use something smarter?

This is my code:

```
public class ListView1 extends ListActivity {
    private DBAdapter db;
    private Cursor getMatchigItems;
    private OnItemClickListener listener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                db = new DBAdapter(this);
                db.open();
                getMatchigItems = db.getMatchingItems(4, 1);
                startManagingCursor(getMatchigItems);

//              SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
//                      android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
//                      getMatchigItems,
//                      new String[]{db.KEYITEMS_TXTITEMNAME, db.KEYITEMS_ROWID},
//                      new int[]{android.R.id.text1});             
//              setListAdapter(adapter);

                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                        R.layout.table_row,
                        getMatchigItems,
                        new String[]{db.KEYITEMS_TXTITEMNAME, db.KEYITEMS_ROWID},
                        new int[]{R.id.textViewItems1});                
                setListAdapter(adapter);

        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(listener);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "id: " + String.valueOf(id) + "\npos: " + String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            };
        });         
    }
}
```

And this is the TableRow layout I wanted to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tableRowLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRowLayoutRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rowcat"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp" android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <View android:id="@+id/imagePlaceholderBlank1Items"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:minHeight="40dp" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/editicon"/>
     <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewItems1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tule bo ime artikla" style="@style/whiteText" android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" android:ellipsize="marquee" android:lines="1" android:focusable="true" android:width="220dp" android:scrollHorizontally="true" android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/imagePlaceholderButton1Items"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:minHeight="40dp"
            android:gravity="center" android:textColor="#FFF" android:background="@drawable/buttonoff" android:tag="off"/>
</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Why are you using a TableLayout? Your layout could be implemented much more effliciently using a horizontal LinearLayout.

Comment: Yes I thought so. The story is that I was inflating some table rows in a table. When I finished the project I found out that it takes Android enormues effort and time to inflate more than about 15 rows, so now I wanted to keep as much finished work as I can... but it looks like I will not :) Is it possible to have an image that changes on click in the list view item?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can't reference TableLayout in the ListView in a normal fashion so I had to use LinearLayout to get onItemClick working.
It even gives you some nice arguments to work with: parent, view, position and the id that I have assigned to the Item with the last Sting (an extra String) in the array.

Notice the 3 TextViews for the "to" parameter and that I've used 4 strings in the "from" parameter. The last one is extra and it must be the "**_id**" key from the database table. It gets assigned to the item ID. Works nice.

```
new String[]{db.KEYITEMS_TXTITEMNAME, db.KEYITEMS_INTIDCAT, db.KEYITEMS_ROWID, db.KEYITEMS_ROWID},
new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.text2,R.id.text3});
```

This is the whole activity:

```
public class ListView2 extends ListActivity {
    private DBAdapter db;
    private Cursor getMatchingItems;
    private ListView lv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testview);

        db = new DBAdapter(this);
        db.open();
        getMatchingItems = db.getMatchingItems(3, 1);
        startManagingCursor(getMatchingItems);


        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.testlistrow,
                getMatchingItems,
                new String[]{db.KEYITEMS_TXTITEMNAME, db.KEYITEMS_INTIDCAT, db.KEYITEMS_ROWID, db.KEYITEMS_ROWID},
                new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.text2,R.id.text3});               
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        lv = getListView();
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long myId) {
                final ListView lvTest = getListView();
                final LinearLayout llTest = (LinearLayout) lvTest.getChildAt(position);
                TextView tv1 = (TextView) llTest.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                tv1.setText("CHANGE");
                tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        String s = llTest.getParent().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                String s = String.valueOf(lvTest.getChildAt(position));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

And this is the XML that I've borowed from [this lovely lady](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html).
She explains it well for the SimpleAdapter. This is just my tweek for the SimpleCursorAdapter.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000fff"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
    </ListView>
<TextView  android:id="@id/android:empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#FFff00"
    android:text="No data"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope someone can find this usefull, or ASAP tell me that's not the way to do it, if they know a better way.
Thanks